# How to check whether location is set by GPS in android application?

Tags: gps, locationmanager, satellite

I need to check whether the location is set by GPS or not in my android application when the 'Use GPS satellite' option is enabled in settings. I can use isProviderEnabled() method to determine whether the 'Use GPS satellite' option is enabled or not. How can I determine whether the Location is set by GPS or not?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the `Location` for its provider using [`getProvider()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getProvider%28%29). It will answer the provider which provided the location / fix.